# What is the Implementation of a Low, Mid or High Tone Dodge or Burn in GIMP?

Tags: image-processing, color, software-implementation

In The GIMP, and also in photoshop, you have the DODGE/BURN tool to enhance colors in shaded or highlighted regions, which would otherwise be blackish or whiteish. I found empirically that this filter is a good preprocessing step for a computer vision task I am implementing.

I found in [Andy Finnell - How to implement dodge and burn tools](http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/09/27/how-to-implement-dodge-and-burn-tools/) that there are 6 formulas which simply map RGB values to other RGB values independently of channel or pixel location. According to the link the transformation is `y=x+0.25*sin(x)` for midtone dodging.

However, I could not verify this with the gimp source code, an excerpt from gimpoperationdodgemode.c:

```
gboolean
gimp_operation_dodge_mode_process_pixels (gfloat              *in,
                                      gfloat              *layer,
                                      gfloat              *mask,
                                      gfloat              *out,
                                      gfloat               opacity,
                                      glong                samples,
                                      const GeglRectangle *roi,
                                      gint                 level)
{
  const gboolean has_mask = mask != NULL;

  while (samples--)
    {
      gfloat comp_alpha, new_alpha;

      comp_alpha = MIN (in[ALPHA], layer[ALPHA]) * opacity;
      if (has_mask)
    comp_alpha *= *mask;

      new_alpha = in[ALPHA] + (1.0 - in[ALPHA]) * comp_alpha;

      if (comp_alpha && new_alpha)
    {
      gint   b;
      gfloat ratio = comp_alpha / new_alpha;

      for (b = RED; b < ALPHA; b++)
        {
          gfloat comp = in[b] / (1.0 - layer[b]);
          comp = MIN (comp, 1.0);

          out[b] = comp * ratio + in[b] * (1.0 - ratio);
        }
    }
      else
    {
      gint b;

      for (b = RED; b < ALPHA; b++)
        {
          out[b] = in[b];
        }
    }

      out[ALPHA] = in[ALPHA];

      in    += 4;
      layer += 4;
      out   += 4;

      if (has_mask)
    mask++;
    }

  return TRUE;
}
```

The essence of the code would boil down to these two lines. The other code is for handling transparency of the brush and iterating over pixels and color channels.

```
gfloat comp = in[b] / (1.0 - layer[b]);
comp = MIN (comp, 1.0);
```

Suggesting a general formula for all tones and both burn and dodge of  `y = x / (1- f(x))`. I could not trace the value of layer[b] back to anything sensible, and hence do not know what `f(x)` is supposed to be.

Moreover, the Wikipedia page on dodge and burn, and general pages about tone mapping, only mention the principle, but not any formulas.

Are there different *definitions* of dodge and burn filters? What is the definition, in the form of a formula `y=g(x)`, of the gimp tool?

Comment: Could you please review my answer? If something is missing, let me know. Otherwise, please mark it.

Comment: A proper mathematical formula be nice. It seems a pixelwise filter, yet its formula is quite unclear. is it something like $\alpha * im + (1-\alpha) * (1-im)$ for range $[0...1]$?

Comment: The code you shoed is equivalent of the `Color Dodge` (See https://photoblogstop.com/photoshop/photoshop-blend-modes-explained). I think the article you linked is about the  Dodge / Burn tool.

Comment: So as I stated, if you want me to accept the answer, IMO it should contain a clear formula or some code on how to apply the Low, Mid and High Tone dodge as asked. As you may understand, I don't really care for the answer anymore, but I do think an answer should be reasonably unambiguous and clear for it to be accepted, which yours frankly isn't.

Comment: I added some information about how to generate the masks to allow the operation to work on different luminosity levels.

Comment: Yes, this is great :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically using what Photographers calls "Shadow Mask" / "Highlight Mask".

If the image is in the range [0, 1] "Highlight Mask" is actually the value of the pixel.
"Shadow Mask" is the inverse, namely 1 - Highlight Mask.

Use this mask as linear interpolator of the result with the originals.

Formalizing it will be:

$$ O \left[ p \right] = M \left[ p \right] A \left( I \left [p \right] \right) + \left( 1 - M \left[ p \right] \right) I \left[ p \right] $$

Where $ p $ is the pixel coordinate (This a pixel wise operation), $ M \left[ \cdot \right] $ is the mask (Low, Mid or High, we'll formalize it soon), $ I \left[ \cdot \right] $ is the input image, $ O \left[ \cdot \right] $ is the output image and $ A \left( \cdot \right) $ is the operation (Doidge or Burn as you got from the source you linked).

The whole trick is the mask. Using it we target Low, Med or High luminosity values.
Assuming $ Y \left[ p \right] $ is the luminosity value of the pixel we can build the masks as:

- High - $ M \left[ p \right] = Y \left[ p \right] $.
- Low - $ M \left[ p \right] = 1 - Y \left[ p \right] $.
- Med - $ M \left[ p \right] = -4 {\left( Y \left[ p \right] \right)}^{2} + 4 Y \left[ p \right] $.

The calculations above assumed data is in the `[0, 1]` range.